# Stored Procedure argument "NULL" or "= NULL"

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, arguments, default

What is the difference between:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure] 
                @MyArgument INT NULL
```

and

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure] 
                @MyArgument INT = NULL
```

I used the first one, and it worked fine in SQL Server 2016. But SQL Server 2012 did not accept it.
Both works on SQL Server 2016, and I am using the second one now without problem. 
But it would be interesting to know the difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

They don't do the same thing. The second one defines a default value for the case that the caller doesn't specify one. The first one doesn't.

The "Transact-SQL Syntax for Natively Compiled Stored Procedures" [grammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) allows parameter datatypes to be declared as allowing `NULL` or `NOT NULL`. This was introduced for Hekaton (memory optimised tables).

Though it isn't documented as supported for the grammar in "Transact-SQL Syntax for Stored Procedures" it looks like it allows `NULL` but balks at `NOT NULL` and throws an error.

> The parameter '@MyArgument' has been declared as NOT NULL. NOT NULL
>   parameters are only supported with natively compiled modules, except
>   for inline table-valued functions.

There is no value in specifying `NULL` explicitly - this is the default and only option. There is no declarative syntax for regular stored procs to indicate that parameters must be `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 5):

They do different things:

1) `@MyArgument INT NULL` - **NULL values are allowed** for parameter @MyArgument

2) `@MyArgument INT = NULL` - **Default value** of parameter @MyArgument is NULL