# Procedure or function 'SlctNxtPrv' expects parameter '@PRV', which was not supplied?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to build a stored procedure with output parameters. However, it requests me to provide value for the outputs.

This procedure is to provide 3 simple things

1. select row based on given id
2. assign id of the previous row to an output parameter
3. assign id of the next row to an output parameter

**SQL Stored procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SlctNxtPrv]   
(
@Art int,   
@PRV int NULL OUTPUT,  
@NXT int NULL OUTPUT  
)  
AS  
BEGIN   
SELECT @PRV = isnull((SELECT TOP 1 id FROM [dbo].[ArtList] where id < @Art ORDER BY id desc),0)  
SELECT @NXT = isnull((SELECT TOP 1 id FROM [dbo].[ArtList] where id > @Art ORDER BY id asc),0)   
SELECT * from [dbo].[ArtList] where [id] = @Art   
END
```

**I execute with this**

```
exec [dbo].[SlctNxtPrv] @Art = 4 ;
```

**and the result comes like this**

```
Procedure or function 'SlctNxtPrv' expects parameter '@PRV', which was not supplied.
```

Comment: I see you  have `@PRV int NULL` this probably doesn't do what you are hoping https://stackoverflow.com/q/59422083/73226. You can set a default and not supply them but this seems pointless for `OUTPUT` params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OUTPUT` parameters don't have a default value (`@OutputParam int NULL OUTPUT` means that the parameters is nullable, not that it has a default value of `NULL`), therefore (just like an "input" parameter) a value must be passed to the SP.

This means that you would have to write something like:

```
DECALRE @Art int,   
        @PRV int,  
        @NXT int;
SET @Art = 4;

EXEC dbo.SlctNxtPrv @Art, @PRV OUTPUT, @NXT OUTPUT;
```

If, however, you want the `OUTPUT` parameters to be optional, you would need to give them a default value, by using `= NULL`. Then you don't have to supply them:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SlctNxtPrv] @Art int,
                                    @PRV int = NULL OUTPUT,
                                    @NXT int = NULL OUTPUT AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @PRV = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 id FROM [dbo].[ArtList] WHERE id < @Art ORDER BY id DESC), 0);
    SELECT @NXT = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 id FROM [dbo].[ArtList] WHERE id > @Art ORDER BY id ASC), 0);
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[ArtList]
    WHERE [id] = @Art;
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.SlctNxtPrv @Art = 4;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5504ab11d5c10cd098308b5eaafd144a)

Answer (score 4):

Just because they're output parameters, they don't magically come into existence on their own when you call the procedure. You still need to supply them at the call site.

```
declare @PRV int
declare @NXT int
exec [dbo].[SlctNxtPrv] @Art = 4, @PRV output, @NXT output ;
--Do something with @PRV or @NXT or both.
```

(Number one cause of bugs IME is forgetting to mark them as `OUTPUT` in the `exec` call, which means they retain their original values when the `EXEC` is complete)

Answer (score 0):

Just declare variable for output and pass it to a stored procedure like this:

```
declare @previous int 
declare @next int 
exec [dbo].[slctnxtprv] @art = 4, @previous output, @next output
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. The OP posted code, at the very least an answer should show them how to correctly call their procedure.

Comment: Sorry I type in my mobile at first time. Then mistake was happen.